# JQuery: How to add an id to a dynamically added element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript which appends an element (a div) to my HTML page after the page is loaded. I would like to add an id to this dynamically div. How can i do that?

Here is more information :
The first js is **myscript1.js** and is loaded at the bottom of the HTML page. In this script I have the following code :

```
$('div#existingDiv').append('<div class="newDiv">Content</div>');
```

The second js is **myscript2.js** and is loaded just after **myscript1.js**. I would like to add an Id.

```
$('div.newDiv').attr('id','div-1234');
```

But it seems that `div.newDiv` does not exist. 
I tried to get the children of `div#existingDiv` (with `$('div#existingDiv').children()`) but it returns an empty result.

Could someone help me?

PS : I can't modify the myscript1.js so please don't suggest me to do what I want to do in the myscript1.js file.

Comment: may be because that div does not exist at that point of time when you are setting the id. If you could post the code where `.append()` happens and where you are setting the id.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but it perfectly works. http://jsfiddle.net/D4L3r/. check your html, may be there is a typo.

Comment: Jai you are true. I put a timeout to execute my code 1s later and it worked. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to work. check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2sL5T/
probably you problem is that

```
$('div.newDiv').attr('id','div-1234');
```

is executed before

```
$('div#existingDiv').append('<div class="newDiv">Content</div>');
```

first you need to find on what event your new html is inserted. is it happening on page load? then maybe you forgot to put your code in onload function?
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Actually, the myscript1.js is a jquery flexslider which appends an ordered list (ol) of thumbnails. What I try to do is to add an id to this ol. The jquery slider starts with "(function ($) {" so it should be correctly loaded. My own script starts with "(function ($) {" as well.
Maybe you are true when my script is loaded the flexslider has not been finished to be executed.

Comment: normally all plugins have callback function.
if you talk about this: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js
it also have. for example
 after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
so you can call it this way:
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    after: function(){
    //put your code here
    }
  });

Comment: Actually, I'm working in the context of a Wordpress plugin development. An existing plugin using flexslider initializes the flexslider. I tried to call $(.flexslider).flexslider({after: function() {...}}); in my own plugin but It didn't work. Maybe because the fleslider is already initialized. I will ask to the developer of the plugin if he can help me. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#existingDiv div.newDiv:last').attr('id','div-1234');
```

This uses the fact that when you append something, it adds at the last.